# Como obterner el tamaño de memoria que utiliza mi sistema operativo android xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

Como obterner el tamaño de memoria que utiliza mi sistema operativo android o xamarin?

Este es mi código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
protected StorageInfo GetStorageInformation(string path)
    {
        StorageInfo storageInfo = new StorageInfo();

        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path); //"/storage/sdcard1"
        long totalSpaceBytes = 0;
        long freeSpaceBytes = 0;
        long availableSpaceBytes = 0;

        /*
          We have to do the check for the Android version, because the OS calls being made have been deprecated for older versions. 
          The ‘old style’, pre Android level 18 didn’t use the Long suffixes, so if you try and call use those on 
          anything below Android 4.3, it’ll crash on you, telling you that that those methods are unavailable. 
          http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2014/09/28/xamarin-and-android-how-to-use-your-external-removable-sd-card/
         */
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr2)
        {
            long blockSize = stat.BlockSizeLong;
            totalSpaceBytes = stat.BlockCountLong * stat.BlockSizeLong;
            availableSpaceBytes = stat.AvailableBlocksLong * stat.BlockSizeLong;
            freeSpaceBytes = stat.FreeBlocksLong * stat.BlockSizeLong;
        }
        else
        {

            totalSpaceBytes = (long)stat.BlockCount * (long)stat.BlockSize;
            availableSpaceBytes = (long)stat.AvailableBlocks * (long)stat.BlockSize;
            freeSpaceBytes = (long)stat.FreeBlocks * (long)stat.BlockSize;
        }

        storageInfo.TotalSpace = totalSpaceBytes;
        storageInfo.AvailableSpace = availableSpaceBytes;
        storageInfo.FreeSpace = freeSpaceBytes;
        return storageInfo;

    }
```

Comment: Nos estas compartiendo tu código o tienes algún argumento que acompañe esto que publicaste?

Comment: si lo estoy compartiendo, es que me devuelve 11.0 GB mi dispositivo tiene 16GB, no me devuelve el espacio que utiliza el sistema operativo, y yo necesito todo